# Sort by distance Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Thank you for your future help! That's my array:

```
var malls: [Mall] = [ 
    Mall(name:"yagey", distance:""), 
    Mall[name:"tigey", distance:"") 
]
```

How can I sort malls by mall.distance?
That's my tableView

tableView

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
    let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
    print (mallLocate)

    let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords) / 1000

    let distanceInMetersString = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMeters)

    for index in 0..<malls.count {
        var mall = malls[index] // copy a mall value
        mall.distance = distanceInMetersString // change the copy of mall
        malls[index] = mall // put the updated mall back into the array
    }

    cell.distanceLabel.text = distanceInMetersString + "км"
    malls.sort() { $0.distance < $1.distance }
    print (mall.distance)


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing sort in tableView's cellForRowAt? it runs once every time a row becomes visible. That is not needed. And also you referenced mall from malls - assuming that is what mallToDisplayAt does, before sorting it, that will give you the value from the unsorted Array first time it is called. Finally, distance is stored in string, to get an accurate comparison during sort you'd need to compare the float/int value during sort instead of the string as string comparison will compare char by char (12 is smaller than 2 because first char is smaller)

Comment: This is the 4th question you've posted today on the exact same problem. Stop doing that. Stick with one question. I told you what to do in your first question. If you have problems getting it to work, edit your question to show your new code at the end and indicate the problem you're having with it.

Comment: I gotta say, though, you seem to be in over your head. You don't understand simple advice like "make the location a property." If you are still learning the basics of Swift then you're not likely to be able to get something as complex as building a table view of locations sorted by distance to the user's location working until you do a lot more studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the malls first, and then use it as TableView's datasource, TableView will display the cells sorted as the order in Array sorted malls:

```
    let sortedMalls = malls.sorted { (mallOne, mallTwo) -> Bool in
        return mallOne.distance < mallTwo.distance
    }
```

Also a one liner:

```
let sortedMalls = malls.sorted { $0.mallOne.distance < $1.mallTwo.distance }
```

Use sortedMalls for:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: @DuncanC, commented at wrong position?

Comment: Yup. Sorry about that. Moving it to the question now.

Comment: @YunCHEN what does it mean "use sortedMalls"? I'm sorry. It's my last question before reading the book)

Comment: @dmarinkin, I mean don't sort malls in UITableView's delegate methods. You should sort the malls first, and then let UITableView to use the sorted malls array. This is a mechanism issue.

Comment: @YunCHEN I understood that, but where I have to add sortedMalls and in which way.. please, help :(

Comment: @dmarinkin,normally, you define a global array for sorted malls. Then, fill it with sorted elements in viewDidLoad() method. After, call TableView's reloadData() method, which will trigger its delegate method like "cellForRowAt indexPath" called to use the global sorted malls array.